# Clickable TextView inside a customized ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I made my own customized `ListView` and in each row there are **2** `TextView`s.

I intend to make those `textview`s inside each row of the `listview` clickable. So whenever the user clicks on any of them, it will redirect him to some other place.

Actually, when the user clicks on a `ListView` item, it clicks all of it, and the `textviews` are being ignored.

In conclusion, when I click on a `ListView` item, I don't want the Listview item to respond, I want the `Textview` inside the `Listview` to respond.

EDIT:

Here is how i customized my view:

```
String[] from = {"value1", "value2"};
int[] to = {R.id.label, R.id.label2};
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, data, R.layout.rowlayout, from, to);
```

Comment: ^ this. What have you tried so far? Did you add OnClickListeners to the individual TextViews or did you override onListItemClick()?

Comment: i have not tried anything yet, what do i try?

Comment: You should use CustomAdapter which extends BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter<T>instead of SimpleAdapter to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Adapter class, inside getview() method you can perform onclick action like this

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    Holder holder = null;
    if (row  == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = 
                (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        holder.txtTitle1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.heading1);
        holder.txtTitle2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.heading2);

        holder.txtTitle1 .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        holder.txtTitle2 .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });
    }
    return row;
}
/////
///////////

static class Holder {
    TextView txtTitle1;
    TextView txtTitle2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set your TextView in your layot.xml

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/YourID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:clickable="true"

/>
```

**and then on your Custom Adapter**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    Holder holder = null;
    if (row  == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = 
                (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = vi.inflate(R.layout.youLayout, null);
        holder.txt1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx1);
        holder.txt2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx2);

       holder.txt1 .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
//your statements            
}
        });

        holder.txt2 .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
//your statements
            }
        });
    }
    return row;
}
```